# Push-out of product of diagrams

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

Im working on the category of groups.
Let $D$ be the push-out of the diagram $B\leftarrow A \rightarrow C$.
Let $D'$ be the push-out of the diagram $B' \leftarrow A' \rightarrow C'$.
It is possible to compute the push-out of the diagram
$B\times B' \leftarrow A\times A' \rightarrow C\times C'$ induced by
the above diagrams?

I thought that the answer was $D\times D'$ but i can't get a simple proof.
Im interested in the case where $B'=\mathbb{Z}^{r_2}, A'=\mathbb{Z}^{r_1} , C'=\mathbb{Z}^{r_3}$ And the homomorphisms of $B' \leftarrow A' \rightarrow C'$ are projections.

Comment: It's true in the category of abelian groups. I see no reason for it to be true in the category of groups.